# How do I remove the border of a WPF window in the Design view/tab?

Tags: wpf, border, designer

I am trying to remove the border of my WPF window in the **design view/tab** in Visual Studio. Please don't mistake this as a request to create a border less WPF window. I did that and it is working fine. What bothers me is that even if you have set `WindowStyle = None`, `ResizeMode = NoResize`, the design view/tab still shows a border around your window in the preview.

Is there a way to remove said border and have a 1:1 preview of the border less window as in Windows Forms?

Every question I have found in regards to this only asks how to remove the border of the actual application. I would like to remove it in the preview.

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

here is a screenshot of my problem:
[image]

Comment: This is not a true preview, it is simply the designer view, that border cannot be removed (it shows the edge of your window). To get a true preview you need to run the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done as this is just how Visual Studio renders a window in design view (I think the frame is probably there so that you can distinguish when you are editing a `Window` rather than a `UserControl`).

Rather than try and find a solution to this I would ask myself if this is something I need to be spending time figuring out - after all you say that your program works correctly when being run. I think your time will be better spent writing code for your program rather than trying to play with the design time environment.

**Update:** In response to you comment, consider that the window frame will be different on every users machine depending on their operating system version (XP vs. Win7) or the theme the user has installed.

My computer has XP installed so the side borders are a lot thinner than those shown in design time so any content will be smaller (but only my a few pixels - 4 in my case; does your user interface design really depend on 4 pixels?).

When using a technology such as WPF you should not be designing your UI to fit to exact pixel sizes; you should be designing with min / max values or using layout containers that adjust to the size of the window as **set by the user.** Any **regions** in your UI (E.G. sidebar and main content) should be expressed as a ratio or percentage of one another; instead of saying "The side bar is 150 pixels wide and the main content area is 350 pixels wide" you should be saying "The side bar takes up a third of the window width and the main content takes two thirds".

Comment: True, however, designing the GUI is difficult, because setting the window to the desired height and width takes the border into consideration and "cuts off" the inner dimension. What I am trying to say is that if you set your Window to 800x480, the design view shows you a window of 800x480 which includes the border. I hope my question makes sense :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is very old and have already been answered (kind of), I just realized: if you set WindowStyle="None", your undesired border is gone.